# Is any way to get the current screenshot?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uiview

I want to develope an app running in the backround that can capture the current screenshot(my device is jailbroken).
The current screen is not just my app's view,my intention is to capture any current screen. 
Or ,is any way to simulate the power button and home button?
Thank you for future help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't take the screenShot by application,The only way to do it by pressing `home + Lock` button.